# Встраивание аудио из вк

Tags: вконтакте, аудио

Возможно ли встроить аудио из социальной сети "в контакте" к себе на сайт?
Хочется иметь возможность добавлять аудио к себе на сайт, не заливая его на сервер. Как встраивается видео из youtube. Есть что-то подобное для аудио из вк или нет? Если нет, то какой сервер хранения аудио лучше всего использовать? Очень важно, чтобы можно было не просто хранить аудио, но и встраивать его плеером у себя на сайте.

Comment: берете линк на файл песни в вк из кода страницы, вставляете ее [в виджет плеера](http://muzicons.com/), получаете код, вставляете его на сайт. Итог - не надо кидать к себе музыку + плеер, как вы и хотели. 1 минута в гугле все выдает по данному запросу.

Comment: @Denis спасибо за ответ, но есть одна проблема. Эти линки динамически изменяются. То есть, сначала всё работает, но через некоторое время в вк линк меняется и встроенная запись перестаёт работать...